# How could I have access to my deleted answer?

Tags: support

I looked at my deleted answers, and found one that was up-voted (score 2), but apparently the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24009044/is-it-possible-to-make-a-completly-generic-spring-mvc-application/24009730#24009730) was deleted.

As I am under 10k rep (and still for a looong time ...) I cannot see that question and so I cannot see my own answer ...

I know that normally questions with upvoted answers should not be deleted (and poster cannot delete them), by I also know that questions really badly asked can allways be deleted for the sake of general quality of the site.

But could somebody over 10k take my answer and post it here ? Or what should be the correct way to recover my text ?

Comment: You can write a query here: http://data.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If the question isn't fit for the site, it is still eligible to be removed by others in the community, regardless of the upvotes on the answers.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I think deleted posts are not accessible from the data explorer IIRC.

Comment: @Makoto I do know and accept it. All I would like were my own text, because as I am not the writer of the question, I have no access to the whole page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the text of the deleted answer:

> Technically, both service and controller layer can be made generic. What I allready saw is are generic abstract services or controllers for the common logic implemented by specialized classes.
>
> You should be aware of a caveat for controllers : if you use a `@RequestMapping` annotation in base class for a given URL, the method called will be that of the base class even if you override it in subclass. And Spring won't allow you to repeat the same `@RequestMapping` in the subclass.
>
> Of course, you can allways use such a construct :
>
> ```
> @RequestMapping( ... )
> public ModelAndView something(params ...) {
>     // pre operations
>     ModelAndView mv = doSomething(params ...);
>     // post operations
>     return mv;
> }
> ```
>
> because the `doSomething` method will be that from subclass if it has been overriden.
>
> Edit:
> Of course the abstract controller can only implement the most basic operations that you will find in all your concrete classes, basically list, view, create, edit and delete. But I could use it for different classes implemententing the same interface.

Unfortunately, when a question gets deleted, the answerers lose access to their posts. So posting on meta requesting for your work is appropriate, in my opinion.

Comment: @SergeBallesta http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266164/do-not-put-edit-or-other-similar-monikers-in-your-posts