# Can't access my own answer on a deleted question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I have answered a potentially not well received question, so the question including my answer was deleted by the community (or even by the OP himself, I don't know). I went to [my list of deleted answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/4136325) to copy it for myself in order to put it in my own Wiki. I see the answer in the list, but I cannot view it ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28584805/how-to-validate-character-data-content-of-tag-in-xml/28585651#28585651) for 10k+).

I know that only 10k+ users can see *other* users deleted questions, but I think that the system shouldn't prevent me from viewing my *own answers*.

Comment: *to copy it for myself* Here would be the link of the source of your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6a49da0d-011a-489c-81fe-da048271ed2c/view-source (I'm not 100% sure, but I think you can access it) Maybe you even can access the revisions of it: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28585651/revisions

Comment: @Rizier123 : no a <10k user can access its deleted questions or answers, but not the answers he wrote on a *deleted question he did not wrote*

Comment: @Rizier123: FYI: I cannot see access the source ("view-source" link), but I can access the revision history ("revision" link).

Comment: @ᵺṓᵯᶏᵴ Ah okay, interesting, as I said I didn't know what you can access and what not :D Now I know it

Comment: @Rizier123: see also the follow-up at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287032/let-me-see-the-source-of-my-own-answers-that-have-been-deleted-please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had [same problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266193/3545273) some month ago. I both asked for it in meta and sent a mail to moderators.

The moderator answer was that the correct way was indeed to ask them for the answer text ... but it came several days after a 10k+ copied my deleted answer in meta.

So here is your answer :

---

Almost any content can be used as text of an element. Any XML library should provide a way to set the text of the element and by doing that, the library will escape all of the five special characters (`>`, `<`, `&`, `"` and `'`). There is no need for CDATA.

In your case, the library would escape the text to

```
<reference>A;&amp;94-230</reference>
```

which is perfectly fine XML. If the destination of the XML also uses a XML library, the library will convert the text back to

```
A;&94-230
```

There's not need to perform a validity before setting the text.

**Edit**

Setting the text

```
string_contains_CDATA-section-close_delimiter ]]>
```

on a `tagelement` will result in

```
<tag>string_contains_CDATA-section-close_delimiter ]]&gt;</tag>
```

which is again valid XML.

**Edit 2**

Find this unit test which uses [JDom](http://www.jdom.org/)

```
@Test
public void XMLSpecialCharacterTest() throws Exception
{
    try
    {
        // Set up everything
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dombuilder= factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream( "<reference/>".getBytes("UTF-8"));
        org.w3c.dom.Document w3cDocument = dombuilder.parse(is);
        DOMBuilder jdomBuilder = new DOMBuilder();
        Document jdomDocument = jdomBuilder.build(w3cDocument);
        Element rootElement = jdomDocument.getRootElement();

        // Do the actual tests
        rootElement.setText("A;&94-230");
        System.out.println(new XMLOutputter().outputString(jdomDocument));

        rootElement.setText("Some text with CDATA ]]>");
        System.out.println(new XMLOutputter().outputString(jdomDocument));
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am about accepting this answer. Do you think the fact that I cannot see access the source ("view-source" link), but I can access the revision history ("revision" link) is worth starting a new question? Or should I post this as an additional answere here?

Comment: @ᵺṓᵯᶏᵴ : do not post that as an answer as it would not be one ! IMHO, you should post it as a new question with a link to this one

Comment: Done, as feature request: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287032/let-me-see-the-source-of-my-own-answers-that-have-been-deleted-please