# Let me see the source of my own answers that have been deleted, please

Tags: feature-request, deleted-answers

This is a follow-up of [a previous question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287028/cant-access-my-own-answer-on-a-deleted-question). In the comments, we found out that I can access the revision history of the deleted answer but not the source code. Those initial links were given by a 10k+ user, but see the following on how I could construct them on my own.

Note that I didn't delete the answer myself. It was deleted because the question was deleted.

Step by step:

- From the [list of my deleted answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/4136325) I can get the [link to the deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28584805/how-to-validate-character-data-content-of-tag-in-xml/28585651#28585651) where I gave an answer.
- Clicking that link gives me a HTTP 404 not found page. Probably because I'm not a 10k+ user.
- Extracting the answer ID (28585651), I can construct [a revision link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28585651/revisions) for my answer which I'm able to access.
- Being there, I wanted to click the [source link](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6a49da0d-011a-489c-81fe-da048271ed2c/view-source) in order to copy the markdown for putting it into my own Wiki.
- Clicking the link gives me a HTTP 404 not found page again.
- Clicking the side-by-side markdown link shows me the markup, but only partly.

My feature request:

a) instead of linking to the deleted question which I am not allowed to see, please link to the answer revision instead. This may be done for <10k users only, and 10k+ users can get the link to the question instead.

b) Let me see the markdown, since I'm the author of it.

Comment: Somewhat related: [Grace Period to recover deleted answer content (User Removed)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276508/1070452)

Comment: Should this also go to meta.SE since it has quite some agreement here?

Comment: The sole answer to this question is itself deleted.