# My deleted answer on deleted question is invisible to me

Tags: bug, deleted-answers

If user A creates a question, user B answers the question, then user B deletes their answer, they can no longer see that deleted answer if user A deletes their question.

This situation happened to me today. I answered a question, deleted my answer, then the question was deleted. Now if I go to my profile, answers tab, scroll to the bottom and click deleted recent answers I see a link to my answer. Clicking on that link gives me Page Not Found. It seems like I should be able to see my deleted answer, and if not there shouldn't be a link to it in my profile.

Comment: I can see my other deleted answers (if I have a link). I believe that 10k just means you can see all deleted Q and A with a link, but anyone can see their own.

Comment: [Very related feature-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287032/let-me-see-the-source-of-my-own-answers-that-have-been-deleted-please)

Comment: @ryanyuyu Thanks for finding a dupe. This just seems off though... I don't understand the logic behind it.

Comment: Unfortunately, the logic behind this design decision was not explained in the duplicate target.  I couldn't find the exact reasoning behind it.  If you edit this question into a "why is it designed this way" support/discussion instead of a bug, it would not a duplicate anymore.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I'll just ask again. I think they're sufficiently different questions.