# Grant access to deleted singleton-answer & question also to <10K rep answerers when question is deleted by owner

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

**Motivation**

This proposal comes from the discussion that occurred on this question: [How did OP delete his question which has an answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313730/how-did-op-delete-his-question-which-has-an-answer)

[This answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266199/3702797) on an other question states:

> when a question gets deleted, the answerers lose access to their posts.

This behaviour led to [this remark](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313730/how-did-op-delete-his-question-which-has-an-answer#comment-289257) from Robert Crovella:

> From answerer's perspective, it's kind of annoying when this happens.

We might all agree that losing a good answer we made just because the OP deleted his question right after he had teh codez, can be frustrating.

While the [amount of questions killing a singleton answer while committing suicide](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313854/statistics-on-answered-questions-deleted-by-their-author/313857#313857) represents *only* 0.6% of open questions scoring greater than or equal to 0 with at least one answer, this behaviour can be really harmful to the motivation of answerers, and especially the ones with <10K rep, which can't even access their own answer anymore.

---

**Proposition**

When a question, with a singleton answer scored at 0, is deleted by its owner:

- The answerer should get a notification around those lines<sup>[1]</sup>:

  > One of your answers got deleted because of the original question's deletion by its owner. You may retrieve it in your [recently deleted answers list](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/userID).
- Users with less than 10K rep, should still be able to access their answer *[, and the question]*.

  ---

**Benefits**

- This would allow answerers to get their work back.
- If they think their answer is valuable enough, answerers will be able to write a new self-answered question. The access to the deleted question can also be needed in order to write an improved question from the original one, and get more views than the original *give me teh codez* version would have got.

  ---

**Appendix**

It may be needed to perform a check on the new question's content to avoid a simple carbon-copy of the deleted one.

Comment: +1 I would generalize this: A <10K answerer should *always* have access to his answer (and possibly the corresponding question), regardless who deleted the question.

Comment: @user000001, I thought it would create some issues with questions flagged as offensive or spam, and for moderation issues. I don't know how long it takes for a question to be removed in these cases, and I guess that allowing only answers to be accessible is a lot more difficult than this proposal. Hence this limitation in my original post, but I may include it if your comment get enough upvotes. At least you've got mine.

Comment: @user000001:  I'd weaken it to always visible unless it has a negative score or wasn't flagged for being offensive.  Having i always available may be risky.

Comment: From the cases I'm aware of where an asker deletes their question after getting an answer, they've all been gimme-teh-codez or it-doesnt-work-why-please-help-me-oh-god-please-URGENT. My view is that those types of question should have been closed in the first place (too broad / unclear what you're asking / duplicate), so I don't have much sympathy for lost answers. I can see the annoyance, but since it potentially discourages answering those types of questions, I think it's actually a positive effect overall (rare cases will always break the trend, but moderators can handle those).

Comment: Problem with that @Dave, though it's a valid example, it's anecdotal (as are all of our experiences, heh). I've had a couple of answers vanish over my time here I think (could be misremembering), but increased UI visibility / access to data would be a good thing, unless there are some backend constraints that make the current implementation preferable.

Comment: @Gorbles: If >10k users can access it, then the data exists, so I would be surprised to hear there is a specific backend constraint preventing exposing it to other users.

Comment: @Dave, while I agree on the nature of such questions, it may also happen they bring some very good answers. In this case, it's even more frustrating to see your answer deleted because of a selfish asker. The proposal if implemented would allow to turn this in a self-answered, improved, question. The ones who only dump teh codez or quick fix probably won't go to this. They won't win any rep and the "positive effect" you see, would still apply, and would even be improved thanks to the notification.

Comment: @MatthieuM. - in principle I agree, the only caveat being load-based, user spread is such that > 10k will be a very minor set of the overall userbase (or even compared to > 1k and < 10k). I'm familiar with database stuff, but by no means an expert, and elsewhere on the Web I'm used to being shouted at for absolutes, heh.

Comment: @Kaiido: I'm not against a notification (it would be nice to get a few more notifications than the system currently gives). It's being able to see the content which I'm opposed to (potential risks include carbon-copies as you already noted, backlashes against the OP, and confusion about whether content is visible to others; e.g. link sharing). Remember that once you reach 10k, you'll be able to see all deleted content anyway, and there's even a search "deleted:1" to find all of your own deleted content.

Comment: @Gorbles: What gives me peace of mind here is the "0.6%" of questions being concerned.

Comment: Sadly, every variation of requesting that <10K users can access *their content* (when it's an answer to a deleted question) has always been declined. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted seems to be the 'mother' of this request and contains most of the pro/con that have been discussed about this. @Dave: didn't know about "deleted:1", thanks for that! Good to know that when I finally start collecting brownie/unicorn points (rep above 10K) that 'problem' is solved in a efficient manner.

Comment: On the other hand, allowing this might lower the motivation to reach 10k :)

Comment: @Leeor: I was also thinking about how to say that as well. I think a lot of people who celebrated hitting 10K (even taking co-workers out for dinner, I've read) didn't celebrate gaining mod-priveleges but finally 'unlocking' the 'hidden' wealth of info (like actually usefull link-only's) and regaining access to their content on deleted questions or making explanatory comments in code linking to a now deleted question working again.  In a way, it's kind of 'unfair' for those who have 'worked' for it. Still, I'll support any proposal that lowers the bar (at least for accessing your own content).

Comment: I should have lost at least 100 answers by now due to Roomba and users closing .htaccess questions because it is .htaccess, or just plain user deletion. Then again, it is already pretty much impossible to find your own answer on a question you answered previously to close as a duplicate. It is much easier to just answer a question in 5-10 minutes than to search for the right duplicate in 30. I stopped caring about most of my answers long ago, because bar a few, no-one will be able to find them anyway.

Comment: @Sumurai8, That's kinda sad, since it beats the goal of StackOverflow as I understand it (or as I understand the community sees it) - it's supposed to be a vault of useful information in a Q&A format, not a voluntary random question answering service.

Comment: @Dave the statistics in the question represent questions which are not downvoted nor closed that are removed shortly after the user gets an answer. This is meant to show the trend of users to ask a question, get the answer they were looking for, then delete their question. Yes this feature request would allow you to view your own answer on more questions than just these, but for users who spend time writing a useful answer to a useful question, only to have the rug pulled out from underneath them by the OP, this would be a way to get that work back and put it to good use.

Comment: @Leeor The ultimate goal is that. The larger community seems to view it differently. When I answer questions in tags as javascript, I am always the last of 3 or 4, because I want to actually explain what I am doing, have a concise styling, etc. When I answer questions in low-traffic tags such as .htaccess, I have people closing the question because they find that more or less amateur setups should go to serverfault, even though it is off-topic there, or no-one with 15+ reps looks at the answer.

Comment: StackOverflow is treated by the larger community, not just people that ask questions, but by people that answer questions too, as a way to get a quick fix, some code they can use or some quick rep. It is also mainly the reason why I don't enjoy answering questions on this site anymore and instead participate in other SE sites.

Comment: Anyway, this feature would not add much. Most answers are not worth keeping. Unless someone asks the same question again, you can likely not use them again. You can look at them every now and then, but you already had the knowledge. It's easier to write another answer than to go through extra hoops just to get a previous answer to use on a different question.

Comment: I've been looking into this (relatively new) "deleted: 1" search option. It only works for *your own posts* and currently only available to >10K users. That means that *if we lower the rep-threshold to use that search-option* from 10K to ??, then we must decide what else you get to see: the question and/or other competing answers and/or comments to either of those? I think this still leaves enough incentive to reach 10K for viewing *the rest* of our knowledge-vault. *Not lowering* the threshold for using this existing option alleviates us from deciding what else you get to see.

Comment: @GitaarLAB I'm told that the "knowledge-vault" of deleted posts is more like a cesspit of ignorance.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: Lol, I to have seen the requests for an option to hide that cesspit for users that obtained 10K `:)`.  But it's not *all* bad: like your own  answer (I hope) on a deleted question or stuff that just wasn't (or no longer is) considered fit for the format of the site (or link-onlys that link to a quality source).

Comment: Citing the advantages of removing clutter from the site does not support the argument to hide content from users that answered deleted questions.  Given that the data is still there and >10k users can access it, I can't think of an actual good reason to hide the removed content from those that produced said content.

Comment: @user1354557 if you mean me, I fully agree with the feature request. My response was only suggesting (in a clearly unclear way) to not allow low-reps to see *the answers of others* on deleted questions. So I suggest concentrating on "seeing own deleted posts", with the unavoidable generalization to "seeing deleted questions to which your answer is linked".

Comment: This feature request is a good idea, why are there no answers from mods or from the dev team? Interesting.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253707/192768 (own answers on deleted Q *and* answers to own deleted Q, not the comment-part) is currently on status-review since Oct. 24, 2015.  More info in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253668/ regarding "deleted: 1" (several (linked) requests, status-completed Dec. 9 2015)

Comment: @Lion: If you're gonna edit a post this old, don't change something as meaningless as "behavior" vs "behaviour". Also, your change from "answerers" to "answers" was simply wrong. I rolled back the edit.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Marking this completed, because the really critical bit is done - but I'll note straight away that the notification you outline will probably never happen (notifying people about deleted posts has nearly always led to problems unless there's a *clear course of action* for the person being notified).

That being said, if you have a link to your answer - or look in the "recent deleted answers" list on your profile - [you'll now be able to view it, even if you don't have 10K](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125828/view-my-deleted-question-and-answer-with-less-than-10k/179511#179511). This should help to reduce frustration and also allow answerers to identify cases of abuse (where the asker is selfishly trying to keep a good answer to themselves for whatever reason).

Comment: I've noticed that as an answerer of a deleted question, I couldn't expand the comments under the question, which contained an explanation of why the question had been closed.

Comment: That sounds plausible; the permissions check that allows you to see the question is predicated on you having answered, but pulling comments does no such check.