# How can I track down my answers to deleted questions?

Tags: support, answers, deleted-questions

I'm not sure if I'm going mad. I've seen a question, that I'm at least 80% sure I've answered already. I remember writing the code, and I'm at least fairly sure I posted an answer.

However, I can't seem to find it. I assume this means the question has been deleted, and thus - effectively - my answer too.

Is there an easy way to find all my answers to (recent) deleted questions, so I can compare? (Or potentially vote to re-open/dupe close, or at the very least refer back to my answer for having another go.)

Comment: Here's another one from today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35671279/hacking-challenge-locating-vulnerability-in-the-code  All such Q & A should go into a 'Queue of Shame' for easy perusal by teachers/profs/TA and their anti-cheat/plagiarism scripts.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313870/grant-access-to-deleted-singleton-answer-question-to-10k-rep-answerers-when

Comment: "deleted"​​​​​​

Comment: If you know the title (ie: it was bookmarked) then you could put into google search and then right-click + open "cached" version. I understand it's not fully what you want , but you could salvage the _answer text_ itself in case it was some deep **** y'know. Share it another day etc . PS: You can re-open _closed_ questions but I think "deleted is deleted". You never know, theres probably a badge for "most undeleted".. Yawn.. am rambling... zzzzz

Answer (score 62):

I have found that `>10k` users can use `deleted:1` in search terms to find *their* answers. This seems to be what I wanted (although, it's still not helping me find the thing that I could have sworn I wrote).

Comment: (The list is slightly longer than I'd thought. Seems there's quite a few instances of OP deleting their post after getting an answer)

Comment: Perhaps people simply feel embarrassed when you answer their questions ;-) because you belong to the high quality participants here.

Comment: I've started flagging homework vamps who pull this trick.  It's annoying and disrespectful:(

Comment: Interesting... I found that I have ~130 answers to deleted questions (~10% of my total answers), some of which (let's say 40?) were, at least in my opinion, quite good answers. The sad part is that most of the questions have been deleted not by an ungrateful OP, but by overzealous 10Kers; it's a bit disappointing to see that, even for stuff that I'd expect be worth at most a close vote as a duplicate (and even in that case often dupe-closers are way too trigger-happy), many are so fast with the delete votes to effectively kill a significant part of work by others.

Comment: Some good/acceptable answers of mine are gone because the user requested an account deletion and somebody had downvoted the question, triggering a deletion by community :(. Is there a way to filter out answers not deleted by owner?

Comment: Sorry to intervene, feel a bit small around here, but.... That is exactly the point! I've been around for almost two years now, and taught myself all the stuff I know. Though I do a lot of research before asking questions, I do sometimes ask ones that are just basic or where I've been stupid without knowing. Unfortunately these questions either get a bad reputation (fortunately I'm not that stupid most of the time) or are criticized by SO itself. If I don't get enough upvotes, my question is considered "bad" and I'm not allowed to ask more. Only solution: Delete some "bad" questions. :/

Comment: @Maverick283 *"If I don't get enough upvotes, my question is considered "bad" and I'm not allowed to ask more. Only solution: Delete some "bad" questions."* Deleting questions doesn't prevent a question ban (afair).

Comment: That's what I thought too, but Help>Question Bans says: *"The ban will be lifted automatically by the system when it determines that your positive contributions outweigh those questions which were poorly received."* And indeed, (I fortunately only had to do it once) when I deleted a question with (I belive) 2 downvotes, I could almost immediately after ask another question. I'm just saying, this might lead new users, or rather the one with little reputation to delete their questions.

Comment: This [Q&A](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) might be helpful here :).

Comment: @Tom but it does say that deleted post are only taken into account when deleted less then 30 days ago. This encourages to delete a question ASAP (as soon as you have the answer) to avoid this ban. 
All I'm trying to say here is that it is encouraged to delete questions as it does (or at least seems to) prevent you of getting a question ban! That's IMHO the wrong approach.

Comment: @Maverick283 One can only delete questions on certain conditions and there are some proposals to restrict this even more (OP shouldn't be able to delete a question if it got at least one answer [you can find them here or on http://meta.stackexchange.com/ ]). So, yes, this would be the wrong approach, but the site works on better ways to detect and avoid abuse of the system.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: deletion has been [getting out of hand](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50967/question-deletions-are-getting-out-of-hand) for a long while, and deletionists are keen on [destroying content](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286970/1269037). After more than [two years in the trenches](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173549/four-year-old-question-with-48-upvotes-and-81-stars-just-got-deleted), I gave up on trying to do anything about this.

Comment: @DanDascalescu: the problem is that the deletionist scum is silent, and is helped by the system in keeping their act stealth. We should really organize - maybe put together a script to keep updated a "urgent undelete needed" queue to make our action effective? Have a "monument men" chat to coordinate us? I mean, 52 up votes to my comment above may mean 1560 undelete votes a day, that *is* something.

Comment: I am pretty sure i am not just having deja vu, when I see a question. But I can't check easily. I assume that means deleted questions.