# Has the policy on ongoing competition or job interview questions changed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions, moderators, dmca-notice

I just noticed that [this upvoted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52566279/establish-base-case-for-recursive-sequence-of-commands-to-reach-target-value/52583264) and my accepted answer to it have been deleted by a diamond ♦ moderator/SO employee. It may not have been a particularly good question, but the asker described the problem, the way he was trying to solve it (recursion), and where he got stuck (establishing a base case to stop the recursion). I see questions much worse than this with the [algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithm) tag daily.

The only unusual thing about the question was this paragraph:

> I can not mention from where I got this problem, because I was asked not to tell. If you know the answer, I can wait a month if you like, I am not in a hurry. I am just curious.

However, afaik questions on Stack Overflow should be judged by themselves, not by whether they are homework, or an online competition, or a job interview, ... See e.g. [this Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278771/how-to-deal-if-the-user-asks-for-code-in-online-programming-competition/278808#278808) on Meta. 
If that was the reason this question was closed, does that mean that this policy has changed?

Comment: My bet's on another DMCA from TestDome.  That's based on the interview-esque feel, and mod deletion.

Comment: Quote: "I can not mention from where I got this problem".  What could go wrong...  It is simply not an *I can republish it where ever I like* escape clause.

Comment: @fbueckert If it is indeed a DMCA request, I'm not going to fight it over 55 imaginary internet points. However, this sort of thing could become highly disruptive on SO; who's going to answer a question that looks like it could be from a test or competition or job interview if it could be deleted any moment?

Comment: It is not that 100's of posts are nuked by DMCA requests on a daily basis. Maybe that number is hit per month but I expect it to be even lower.

Comment: also related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317709/what-is-the-policy-for-dmca-takedowns-and-what-can-we-expect-in-terms-of-transp/317712#317712

Comment: @rene That's assuming I'm right.  I very well could be barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: @rene I saw at least one exact duplicate of this question; I guess there's going to be more people who use that test site and then come to SO because they're curious about questions they couldn't find an answer to.

Comment: One request per month: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311708/158100 but I'm not sure if one request contains multiple posts.

Comment: @m69 it is fine to ask a question about an online test / competition as much as it is about your homework assignment as long as you didn't dump the assignment here in a question to have it solved for you instead of learning from  a failed attempt in solving it.

Comment: @m69: **any** question can be deleted at any moment if a valid DMCA notice is filed.

Comment: @m69 If you actually think there's a useful question in there that would actually be applicable to a wide audience, then write your own version of the question without using any copywrited material and post a new question.

Comment: So.. I might be off on the wrong foot here but basically.. any question can be deleted by the likes of Codility and TestDome via DCMA etc because they run some online programming tests? What if they get a question from StackOverflow and post it as a test? What worries me is that any new website that suddenly realises they want to ask a question on a test that already has answers to it can just ask to remove this question from the website? If that's not stupid then I don't know what is - I'm lacking some knowledge on the topic so don't assume I'm just ranting, I'm looking for clarification :)

Comment: PS, I just read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317709/what-is-the-policy-for-dmca-takedowns-and-what-can-we-expect-in-terms-of-transp) so the above is clarified. But I still call it a little bullcrap and unfair, that's just my opinion. Life goes on.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No policy has changed.

The post was deleted because of a *DMCA notice*, not because it concerns a contest. There is a comment on the question, left by the employee that deleted the post:

> Post removed due to a DMCA notice from Codility

Also see [What is the policy for DMCA takedowns, and what can we expect in terms of transparency regarding the removed content?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317709/what-is-the-policy-for-dmca-takedowns-and-what-can-we-expect-in-terms-of-transp) over on Uber Meta.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't expand the hidden comments because the question is deleted and I'm <10k.

Comment: @m69 - That's interesting. You could see the deleted question because you had answered it or something? I thought <10k couldn't see the deleted question page at all (unless it was theirs).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes it's been done finally https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345843/3702797

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, I could see the question and my answer, and I could expand the comments under my answer, but not those under the question.

Comment: @m69 - Sounds like a bug to me. If you can see the question, you should be able to see the comments on it (for exactly this reason). Perhaps worth a [tag:bug] question...